# Accessing objects of parent class in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, class, parent-child

I have a main AppDelegate class (MacOS development, not iOS) initiating a child class with

```
myChildClassObject=[[myChildClass alloc]init:self];
```

So I do send the parent reference to the child class.
However how can I access an object of my parent class from my child class ?
I tried with

```
parent.myObject
```

but it doesn't find it.

My parent class is defined like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSView *myObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSView *myObject;
@end
```

My child class is defined like this:

```
@interface Gfx
{
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things here:

1)  You can easily get a reference to an application's delegate via this line:

```
AppDelegate * appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

2)  If you want to store a reference to the parent in the child, you can do something like this:

add a property to your child's .h @interface file that looks like this:

```
@property (retain) id parent;
```

Then, in your parent class and right after instantiating your child object, you can do:

```
ChildObject * child = [[ChildObject alloc] init];
child.parent = self;
```

And you can refer to the parent class from within the child via:

```
self.parent;
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, however I still don't succeed in what I am looking for. I followed your steps, but still can't access parent's object from the child: self.parent.myObject is not recognized... How should I declare the myObjet in the parent class ? Thanks

Comment: The reason it's not recognized is because you're saving "`parent`" as an "`id`", which is analagous to declaring a variable with a "`void *`". The app doesn't know what kind of object "`parent`" really is.  You need to cast "`self.parent`" into some variable, then you should be able to retrieve the "`myObject`" property.

Answer (score 1):

First I assume your child class is defined as:

```
@interface Gfx : NSObject
```

(The `NSObject` is omitted in the question, you also call it both `Gfx` and `myChildClass`) I.e. your "child" is not a subclass of your "parent".

You have not given the declaration of the `Gfx` `init` method, so we guess:

```
- (id) init:(id)parent
```

Now the "dot" syntax for accessing properties relies on the *static* type of the variable holding the object reference and not the actual type of the reference object. So if you have:

```
id parent; // instance variable
```

and

```
parent.myObject
```

then the compiler will object as `id` does not have a property `myObject`. Two solutions:

(a) call the setter/getter methods directly, e.g.:

```
[parent myObject];      // get the value of the property
[parent setMyObject:e]; // set the value of the property to e
```

This works as the compiler treats `id` specially and performs no static type checking on calls, the methods are found dynamically at runtime only. However this also raises a problem, what if the object referenced by `parent` does not have a `myObject`/`setMyObject` method? You will get an error at runtime.

(b) Type or cast `parent` correctly. To type you would change the instance variable and `init` declarations to use `AppDelegate`, e.g.:

```
- (id) init:(AppDelegate *)parent
```

This will give you static (compile time) type checking and dot notation. You can also use a cast, leaving `parent` as `id` you can use:

```
((AppDelegate *)parent).myObject; // compiler will be happy
```

However this does not check that `parent` *is* does reference an `AppDelegate` object - a cast is a "trust me" instruction to the compiler. So using casts bypasses static type checking, but runtime checks are still performed.

HTH

Comment: Thanks CRD, it does fully make sense !