# Cocoa/Objective C (OSX NOT IOS) accessing parent Object from child

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, object, parent-child

i am new in STackOverflow and new to ObjectiveC. I did a lot of research and already found some answers like: [Accessing objects of parent class in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706592/accessing-objects-of-parent-class-in-cocoa)

Still, i have some problems in understanding it and i hope the community may help to understand:

I have a ViewController, inside this controller i create an instance of a custom NSObject Class. I'd like to access the ViewController's (parent) properties and methods from the object instance.

*MYCustomViewController.h*

```
@interface MYCustomViewController : NSViewController

// Vars
@property BOOL testBool;

@end
```

*MYCustomViewController.m*

```
@implementation MYCustomViewController

- (void) someMethod
{
    self.testBool = true;
    _importController = [[MYCustomObject alloc] init];
    [_importController test];
}

@end
```

*MYCustomObject.h*

```
@interface MYCustomObject : NSObject
- (void)test;
@end
```

*MyCustomObject.m*

```
@implementation MYCustomObject

- (void)test
{
    // HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THIS?
    myParent.testBool; // --> true

    // AND THIS?
    [myParent someMethod];
}

@end
```

I am still learning, so any (not too short) explanation would be great.
Idea was: send "self" on object instantination, but how?

Targeting OSX 10.10, Xcode 8, OSX 10.12

EDIT: Got it to work using protocol on MYCustomObject. Is there any other possibility with the above mentioned idea?

Comment: Read [ask] and check out the [faq]. Stackoverflow is not a forum. You don't edit your question to include your solution, you post an answer. Also, leave out the "I am new here...". It doesn't matter that you're new since the same standards apply to _all_ questions. Just the facts. And do read the first page I linked to very carefully.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will take care of it next time a post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C (and Swift) have no language concept of "parent object" being the object that created an object. (There is a parent/child relationship in classes.) If your model requires a parent connection then you simply pass the creating parent to an `init` method.

For example, given class `MustHaveParent` the following might be defined:

```
@implementation MustHaveParent
{
   id myParent; // reference to my parent
}

- (instancetype) initWithParent:(id)parent
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
      myParent = parent;
   return self;
}
```

and an instance of this class might be created using:

```
// myChild is a *local* variable, see below
MustHaveParent *myChild = [[MustHaveParent alloc] initWithParent:self];
```

If your model does require such a reference you should be careful not to create a reference cycle, where the parent references the child and the child references the parent. This is why the example above uses a local variable, if the reference had been stored in an instance variable of the creator there would be a cycle. While not always bad cycles often cause memory leaks. If you need to know more about this look up "reference cycles", "strong references", "weak references" etc.

HTH